# Discrete log zero knowledge proof lying case

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I read the Wikipedia page on [a discrete log zkp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof#Discrete_log_of_a_given_value), but I don't understand how

$$C' = g^{r'} \cdot (g^x)^{-1} \bmod p$$  would be calculated.

Would it be  $$C' = g^{r} \cdot \frac{1}{y} \bmod p$$  where $y = g^x \bmod p$

When I run the following code to check the current implementation (the one I suggested above), I consistently get false positives.

```
if g ** Prover.trial_request(return_r) % p != (C*(y % p)):
    return False
```

I can't see to find my error, but I have narrowed it to this case. Any pointers would be helpful

Comment: $(g^x)^{-1}$ denotes the modular inverse of $g^x$ modulo $p$.

Comment: @Maeher to clarify, does $(g^x)^{-1} \bmod p$ denote the inverse of $(g^x) \bmod p$ or does $(g^x)^{-1}$ denote the inverse of $(g^x) \bmod p$? In essence, does it expand to $((g^x) \bmod p)^{-1}$ or to $(g^x) \bmod p)^{-1} \bmod p$

Comment: The calculation happens in the finite ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$. So in notation ' mod p'  should be the rightmost part - it affects the entire expression / equation / calculation. There are no 'regular' fractions like the rational numbers here.

Comment: @tylo sorry, I'm a little unclear as to what you are referring to when you say it should be to the rightmost part. Are you referring to one of the equations in the comment above yours or in the original question?

Comment: Please check the Latex edits. Normally you can copy them from Wikipedia by clicking edit button and looking for <math> tag. Did you forget to include the ' in the second equation?

Comment: @kelalaka Ah yes. I was aware of this, but for some reason was under the false impression that crypto doesn't support Tex.

Comment: @Maeher upon further review, I realized the reason I thought it would be $y^{-1}$ is because the verifier does not have access to $x$ and thus not $g^x$. They are given $g$, $r$, $y$, and $p$, hence why I followed that line of reasoning to $C' = g^r * (y)^{-1} \bmod p$

Comment: @vvm32812 To make it more clear: Your expression $(... \mod p)^{-1}$ ist wrong. 'Mod p' affects the entire expression. The inversion happens in the finite field, it doesn't get you out of the finite field into rational numbers. And with  "rightmost" I meant: In the expression it is the part at the end of it, nothing comes after it.